# MongoDB querying to get data with aggregate in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, cloud, aggregation-framework

```
$filter = array();
$options = array("sort" => array("age" => -1));
$query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
```

In this type of method is for mongo queries like db.collection.find({age:-1}), but i wanted method to do aggregate queries like below to run in PHP and get the data in maybe var_dump? So i can use the Data in my PHP.

QUESTION: What if I want a aggregate query like this to run in my PHP to get the DATA?

```
db.catalog.aggregate(
    [     
    {$unwind: '$productOrdered'},
    {$group: {_id: '$productID', 'totalOrdered': { $sum: 1}}} 
    ]
    );
```

==================> To get the number of times the product was purchased

collection look like

```
-productID,

-productName,

-productOrdered{

    customerID,

    dateofpurchse,

}
```

PREVIOUSLY I was using this method like below, worked fine in localhost, but when I upload in CLOUD it doesnt work, so left me with changing to other methods, maybe like to above one. If i can run in Cloud I would stick with this.
- AliCloud

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient("localhost");

$c = $m->selectDB("examples")->selectCollection("article");

$data = array (
   'title' => 'this is my title',
   'author' => 'bob',
   'posted' => new MongoDate,
   'pageViews' => 5,
   'tags' => array ( 'fun', 'good', 'fun' ),
   'comments' => array (
     array (
       'author' => 'joe',
       'text' => 'this is cool',
       ),
     array (
       'author' => 'sam',
       'text' => 'this is bad',
       ),
     ),
   'other' =>array (
     'foo' => 5,
     ),
   );
$d = $c->insert($data, array("w" => 1));

$ops = array(
   array(
    '$project' => array(
        "author" => 1,
        "tags"   => 1,
        )
    ),
   array('$unwind' => '$tags'),
   array(
    '$group' => array(
        "_id" => array("tags" => '$tags'),
        "authors" => array('$addToSet' => '$author'),
        ),
    ),
   );

$results = $c->aggregate($ops);
var_dump($results);
?>
```

Comment: What's the error message you are seeing using the original code in the cloud?

Comment: @dnickless there is no error msg, it's just data not appearing but when i use the filter options method it displays the data